# Factoring constant in summation

Tags: summation

Trying to show that adding a constant c to $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^kx_k$, where a is a constant will just add some constant k to the summation

eg. $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n(x_n+c)$$
$$=k + \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^nx_n$$
and then work out what k is in terms of x and c.

I'm not really sure how to work with things inside summations, would it work something like this?
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n(x_n+c) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^nx_n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^nc$$
so $$ k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^nc$$

$$k = \frac c{1-a} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct as long as the sums converge absolutely, which requires that $|a| \lt 1$ and the $x_n$ are well enough behaved. If they do not converge absolutely you cannot change the order of summation like this without some additional argument.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.